# How do I reset network and internet connectivity on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS in VMware?

Tags: networking, vmware, dhcp

I have this KDE Plasma UI, and that's how I can still interact with the OS, but it has lost all connectivity; the browser can't connect, I can't ping, and SSH won't connect to its fixed IP from Windows 11 either.

How did I mess up? There is a Discover app that I guess could install updates visually, and it had no connectivity due to some bug. I wanted to try it, and an answer told me to change the renderer of the network in netplan to the one affected by the GUI, then Discover began working. It didn't last long, and I lost all connectivity after a restart. Since then, I've been typing (since copy-paste doesn't seem to work with this VMware integration, very cumbersome) all kinds of commands to the terminal from StackExchange. Such as restarting the interfaces and stuff like that but no joy.

It used to require no configuration whatsoever from within Ubuntu. Perhaps VMware performed it, and I messed it up? But shouldn't it "just work" with DHCP? I'm essentially just reserving a (the first) IP for it in VMware.

Let me know if you need more info. I have a too-late backup of the entire virtual disk, 80GB, but connectivity fails after a restart. And even when it works, it shows a fixed 50% packet loss.

[image]

[image]

vmnetdhcp.conf This is how I give it a fixed IP.

```
allow unknown-clients;
default-lease-time 1800;                # default is 30 minutes
max-lease-time 7200;                    # default is 2 hours

# Virtual ethernet segment 8
# Added at 08/30/22 20:17:59
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.2.22 192.168.2.254;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.2.2;
    option domain-name "localdomain";
    option netbios-name-servers 192.168.2.2;
    option routers 192.168.2.2;
    default-lease-time 1800;
    max-lease-time 7200;
}
host VMnet8 {
    hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:08;
    fixed-address 192.168.2.1;
    option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
    option domain-name "";
    option routers 0.0.0.0;
}
# End
host ubi {
    hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:CB:5A:9E;
    fixed-address 192.168.2.22;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For use in a GUI, the renderer should be set as: `renderer: NetworkManager`

You could be getting packet loss because you have cloned the VM and it is currently running elsewhere, or you have some other device using the same MAC/IP address?